# Laws of addition of Vectors

Tags: vectors

How **Triangle Law and
Parallelogram law of addition** of
Vectors are different?*Ain't they.*

Please don't tell me the things
written in book......give me the
appropriate reason.And how do i distinguish between the two while adding vectors,what am i trying to say is i get really confused where to use parallelogram law and where triangle law

P.s:my basics are really weak though!May be the question might not be right

Comment: If I understand your post correctly, then these two rules yield the same result. Maybe you should draw a few examples, then it will probably become more clear. Maybe have a look at http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3d/Vector_Addition.svg/400px-Vector_Addition.svg.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How Triangle Law**and **Parallelogram law of addition of Vectors are different?Ain't they.

They are not different.

They are the same thing. There is only one real law which is the head to tail rule. When adding any number vectors put head to tail, head to tail, head to tail... until all the vectors are used up and then draw a line from the tail to the head and that is your resultant vector.

The parallelogram law is essentially just using the triangle law twice in a different order, and they both get the same answer because order does not matter I.E. $\vec A+ \vec B = \vec B + \vec A$.

[Here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/imgmec/vec8a.gif) shows the addition of three vectors, the "triangle" rule has been used twice in a row to get $\vec A+ \vec B + \vec C = \vec R$. If yo tried to use the parallelogram to get this answer the resulting diagram would be a mess of repeatedly writing the same vector and over.